# Ehcache-monitor exception when application starts

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have an app that uses hibernate and EHCache as a 2nd layer cache. I want to monitor the activity of cache and I found ehcache-monitorr tool which seems very nice.
After I followed instruction from readme I and I added echcache-probe  jar in may classpath and define:

```
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory 
        class="org.terracotta.ehcachedx.monitor.probe.ProbePeerListenerFactory"   
        properties="monitorAddress=127.0.0.1, monitorPort=9889, memoryMeasurement=true" />
```

The app won't start anymore and fails with exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.terracotta.ehcachedx.monitor.probe.ProbePeerListenerFactory cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.distribution.CacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCachePeerListeners(ConfigurationHelper.java:163)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:786)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:471)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
... 79 more
```

I use ehcache-probe-1.0.3 and ehcache 2.9.1.
Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your versions are not compatible. Probe type is expected, different one is obtained - thus class cast. That should not happen in matched systems, so I suspect mismatch.

Since newest probe in [Maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.terracotta/ehcache-probe) is 1.0.2, so even older than yours, I'd say tool won't work.

But, since 2.7, EHCache seems to have [monitor built-in](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/operations/monitor.html), how about that?